# htmx - focus element (non javascript)

Tags: html, htmx

How are elements focused in htmx?

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

The goal is to focus a specific element after a POST request i.e. focus the input with id `#field-description`.

I'd like this to be done without javascript, if possible.

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <span>Description</span>
    <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="task" id="field-description">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <span>Amount</span>
    <input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="number" id="field-amount">
</div>

<button 
    hx-post="/api/todos" 
    hx-include="#field-description, #field-amount"
    hx-target="#todos-container" 
    hx-swap="innerHTML"
    hx-focus="#field-description"
>
    Add
</button>

<div id="todos-container" class="todos-container">
    ${getTodos()}
</div>
```

Comment: Seems that the element can have the basic HTML `autofocus` attribute? At least based on their example here [here](https://htmx.org/examples/progress-bar/) used with a `h3` element. Obviously, that will also focus before a post though.

Comment: This is only for the initial focus. When I shift focus to other inputs and submit the data, I want to re-focus the first input. autofocus does not cover this use case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think htmx has any `hx` attribute for that behaviour. You can try the `hx-on` attribute which accepts an inline JavaScript expression. On your **Add** button, you can add:

```
hx-on::after-settle="document.getElementById('field-description').focus()"
```

But this is rather too much much work for such a simple case. I would suggest you just add an `autofocus` attribute on the input you need initial focus on.

```
<input type="text" name="description" .... autofocus>
```

Comment: The initial focus is useful. My idea was to focus the field after each button press i.e. content swap. I am amazed this has not been solved. It should be a default in the htmx library.

Comment: I suspect it isn't available for the simple reason that htmx is not built for interactivity. For 'non-JavaScript' interactivity, the creators of htmx made hyperscript. Maybe take a look at that?

Comment: There's an issue discussing this suggestion: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/1869